# How to find firefox in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox

I bought a Macbook Pro yesterday and installed firefox.  I used firefox a few times, but now I can't find it.  How can I find where it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something else that might have happened is that you ran Firefox directly from the DMG instead of actually "installing" it.

Firefox comes in what is called a DMG. DMGs are basically virtual disks that hold data, and then when you double-click them they essentially "plug in" to the system, and look just like another drive. What you may have done is run Firefox directly from the DMG, instead of "installing" Firefox. Then, perhaps after a reboot, the DMG got unmounted (essentially "unplugged", no longer looking like a drive) and so you couldn't find the icon any more. It's an easy mistake to make.

To actually "install" something from a DMG in Mac is really easy. [Here's how.](http://theappleblog.com/2008/04/22/beginning-mac-application-installuninstall/)

Comment: the "Here's how." link doesn't work anymore, the target blog seems to be deleted

Answer (score 9):

In the upper right hand corner, there is a magnifying glass.  That is the spotlight search feature of OS X.  Click it and type in 'firefox' and press enter and it will show you where anything to do with 'firefox' is. It would likely be under the Applications folder, but it could be put anywhere and ran.

[image]

Comment: what he said ^ . You can also access spotlight more easily by pressing  "control-space" and beginning to type firefox. It should find it within seconds. 

Of course this assumes that you have installed firefox on your mac. If you didn't, go to http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html and click on download.

Answer (score 3):

You can find it in the /Applications folder.
Anyway, install QuickSilver to launch applications quickly by typing parts of their names.